# UWP C# UART data buffer to use Array or List?

Tags: c#, arrays, uwp, uart, windows-iot-core-10

I am working on UART-RS485. The data is sent in bytes. I have tested with hard-coded code using `array`. However, I would like to find out how to use array in a dynamic matter as the data packet size may vary.

```
 Task<UInt32> storeAsyncTask;

 byte[] data = { 0xF5, 0x81, 0x66, 0x0F, 0x00, 0x6B }; 
 dataWriteObject.WriteBytes(data);

 storeAsyncTask = dataWriteObject.StoreAsync().AsTask();

 UInt32 bytesWritten = await storeAsyncTask;
```

Please help thanks.

Updated:
I recently tried using `bitconverter` but it doesn't work. I am not sure where I did wrong.

```
        Task<UInt32> storeAsyncTask;

        BitConverter.GetBytes(F5).CopyTo(data, 0);
        BitConverter.GetBytes(TxAddress).CopyTo(data, 1);
        BitConverter.GetBytes(TxCommand).CopyTo(data, 2);
        BitConverter.GetBytes(TxData).CopyTo(data, 3);
        BitConverter.GetBytes(~TxData).CopyTo(data, 4);

        TxChkSum = 0;

        foreach (byte a in data)
        {
            TxChkSum += a;
        }

        BitConverter.GetBytes(TxChkSum).CopyTo(data, 5);

        dataWriteObject.WriteBytes(data);

        storeAsyncTask = dataWriteObject.StoreAsync().AsTask();

        UInt32 bytesWritten = await storeAsyncTask;
```

Update 23-01-2020

I tried using the `list` method but by `addrange` the data is added in range of 2 bytes(16-bits) instead a one byte (8 bits) where the RS485 communication i am interfacing is transmitted in byte by byte. May I know how to work around it?

[image]

2nd issue is that at `dataWriteObject.WriteBytes(data.ToArray());`it throw an exception as follow;

```
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
```

[image]

I am not sure what does it mean and how to overcome it.

eg.

```
byte F5 = 0xF5;
byte TxCommand= 0x66
byte TxData = 0x0F

        try
        {
            List<byte> data = new List<byte>();

            data.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(F5));
            data.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(TxAdr));
            data.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(TxCommand));
            data.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(TxData));
            data.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(~TxData));

            TxChkSum = 0;

            foreach (byte a in data)
            {
                TxChkSum += a;
            }
            data.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(TxChkSum));

            dataWriteObject.WriteBytes(data.ToArray());

            Task<UInt32> storeAsyncTask;
            storeAsyncTask = dataWriteObject.StoreAsync().AsTask();

            UInt32 bytesWritten = await storeAsyncTask;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MainStatusDisplay.Text = ex.Message;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[BitConverter.GetBytes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter?view=dotnet-uwp-10.0) is used to convert base data types to an array of bytes, and an array of bytes to base data types. Please see following code.

```
            byte[] data = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 , 0x00  };

            double aDouble = 0.11;
            BitConverter.GetBytes(aDouble).CopyTo(data, 0);
```

After called CopyTo method, the data array will be filled with this result.

```
0x29 0x5c 0x8f 0xc2 0xf5 0x28 0xbc 0x3f 0x00 0x00
```

So that, if the size of converted buffer is bigger than the target data array which you want to copy to, there will be an overflow exception. You may try with following code.

```
            List<byte> data = new List<byte>();

            data.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(F5));
            data.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(TxAddress));
            data.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(TxCommand));
            data.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(TxData));
            data.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(~TxData));

            TxChkSum = 0;

            foreach (byte a in data)
            {
                TxChkSum += a;
            }

            data.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(TxChkSum));

            dataWriteObject.WriteBytes(data.ToArray());
```

**UPDATE:**
In fact, in your scenario, it is not necessary to convert the byte data by BitConverter. You may try to use following code.

```
            List<byte> data = new List<byte>();

            data.Add(F5);
            data.Add(TxAddress);
            data.Add(TxCommand);
            data.Add(TxData);
            data.Add(~TxData);

            TxChkSum = 0;

            foreach (byte a in data)
            {
                TxChkSum += a;
            }
```

Comment: Hi @MichealXu-MSFT Thanks... i have tried the `list` method but i encountered addition problem.. i have updated the post... I am not sure how to overcome it... can you please advise.

Comment: @mylim, please make sure the 'dataWriteObject' has been initialized, the error means the 'dataWriteObject' is null. I have updated the response.