# UWP C# Windows IoT Core UART RS485 Error After Multiple Transmission

Tags: c#, uwp, uart, windows-iot-core-10, rs485

this is a related post to my previous question regarding [RS485 Data Buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59851585/uwp-c-sharp-uart-data-buffer-to-use-array-or-list/59855013?noredirect=1#comment106072789_59855013).
I intended to transmit to multiple slave devices from 1 to maybe 50. current I only have 6 slaves devices setup.
I am testing a `transmit all` routine where i have a `dispatchertimer` with a `timespan` of `10ms` interval to transmit `6 bytes` to data at `4800baudrate` to each slave. 
I will `start` the `dispatchertimer` when triggered to transmit and `stop` the `dispatchertimer` after sending to the last slave device.

[image]
I encounter error code `0x80004005` `External components has thrown an exception` when the second `transmit all` is triggered in my `tx485` routine as follow;

```
            // Configure serial settings
            serialPort.WriteTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(-1);//10 //1000
            serialPort.ReadTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(-1);//100 //1000
            //serialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
            serialPort.BaudRate = 4800;
            serialPort.Parity = SerialParity.None;
            serialPort.StopBits = SerialStopBitCount.One;
            serialPort.DataBits = 8;
            serialPort.Handshake = SerialHandshake.None;

private async void Tx485()
    {
        if (serialPort != null)
        {


            List<byte> data = new List<byte>();

            data.Add(F5);
            data.Add(TxAdr);
            data.Add(TxCommand);
            data.Add(TxData);
            data.Add(comTxData);

            TxChkSum = 0;
            foreach (byte a in data)
            {
                TxChkSum += a;
            }

            TxChkSum = (byte)(TxChkSum - 0x80);
            data.Add(TxChkSum);

            try
            {
                // Create the DataWriter object and attach to OutputStream
                dataWriteObject = new DataWriter(serialPort.OutputStream);

                dataWriteObject.WriteBytes(data.ToArray());

                Task<UInt32> storeAsyncTask;
                // Launch an async task to complete the write operation
                storeAsyncTask = dataWriteObject.StoreAsync().AsTask();

                UInt32 bytesWritten = await storeAsyncTask;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MainStatusDisplay.Text = ex.Message;
            }

        }
        else
        {
            MainStatusDisplay.Text = "No UART port found";
        }
    }
```

Thanks.

Edited 2020-02-25

To add .. the 485 transmission is triggered by a `timeschedule`. 
Once the `timescheudle` is triggered ... it will transmit the `on` signal to all the devices and at the same time to play an audio file. 
once the audio file `mediaended` .. it will `start` a 2 seconds delay timer then transmit `off` signal again to all the devices. 
I do not have issue when transmitting the `on` signal but only when transmiting `off` signal during `mediaended` and the program.

```
private async void Schedule_MediaEnded(MediaPlayer sender, object args)
    {
        await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            try
            {
                scheduleEndedTxOff = true;
                commsDelay.Start();    //commsdelay delays 2 seconds before starting transmitting `OFF` signal
            } catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MainStatusDisplay.Text = ex.Message;
            }
        });
    }

private void CommsDelay_Tick(object sender, object e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (scheduleEndedTxOff)
            {
                scheduleEndedTxOff = false;
                if (allDecoderOn == true)
                {
                    commsDelay.Stop();
                    txAll = true;
                    DecoderAddress = maxDecoder;
                    allOff = true;
                    allOn = false;
                    TestTxToDecoder.IsEnabled = false;
                    commsTimer.Start();  //CommsTimer_Tick
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MainStatusDisplay.Text = ex.Message;
        }

    }

private async void CommsTimer_Tick(object sender, object e)
    {
        if (txAll)
        {
            if (allOn)
            {
                try
                {
                    var a = DecoderAddress | 128;
                    TxAdr = Convert.ToByte(a);
                    TxCommand = TxUpdateSts;
                    TxData = 0x0F;
                    comTxData = (byte)(~TxData);
                    Tx485();
                    DecoderAddress--;

                    if (DecoderAddress == 0)
                    {
                        DecoderAddress = maxDecoder;
                        txAll = false;
                        allOn = false;
                        allOff = false;
                        allDecoderOn = true;
                        commsTimer.Stop();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    commsTimer.Stop();

                    await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
                    {
                        MainStatusDisplay.Text = ex.Message;
                    });
                }
            }

            if (allOff)
            {
                try
                {
                    var a = DecoderAddress | 128;
                    TxAdr = Convert.ToByte(a);
                    TxCommand = TxUpdateSts;
                    TxData = 0x00;
                    comTxData = (byte)(~TxData);
                    Tx485();
                    DecoderAddress--;

                    if (DecoderAddress == 0)
                    {
                        DecoderAddress = maxDecoder;
                        txAll = false;
                        allOn = false;
                        allOff = false;
                        allDecoderOn = false;
                        commsTimer.Stop();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    commsTimer.Stop();

                    await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
                    {
                        MainStatusDisplay.Text = ex.Message;
                    });
                }
            }

        }
    }

private void initCommsTimer()
    {
        commsTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        commsTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10);
        commsTimer.Tick += CommsTimer_Tick;
    }
```

`Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in 485comms.exe
WinRT information: Slave address was not acknowledged.
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in 485comms.exe
WinRT information: Slave address was not acknowledged.
The thread 0x11c4 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x11cc has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x1794 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x12f0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x12e8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x12f8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x1044 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[0x170C] 485comms.exe' has exited with code -1073741811 (0xc000000d).`

Update: 2020-02-26
I have uploaded the sample code here.
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnzY25rC-8ZkmO1SAOGwLj28HOlKxg?e=2mOEz2

Answer (score 0):

When you update the content of the component in non-UI thread, you need to use  [CoreDispatcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.dependencyobject.dispatcher) that can be used to marshal calls coming from non-UI threads, here is your code, the DispatcherTimer in a non-UI threads.

```
    await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
    {
        MainStatusDisplay.Text = ex.Message;
    });
```

**Update**:

When I run your project, the app crashes with error `Value does not fall within the expected range.`. We recommend you to add `try catch` to every method for troubleshooting the issue. I guess the error System.IO.FileNotFoundException caused by the audio files or other resources used in your app are missing in your solution.

Comment: Hi... I did a bit of troubleshooting after using `coredispatcher` ... I found that the exception also thrown at the `listen` routine after multiple consecutive transmissions.. the error message is `+  ex {"The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800703E3)"} System.Exception` ...

Comment: Which line of code you run to will show the above error? If possible ,please provide more code so that i can debug in my device.

Comment: Hi @MichealXu-MSFT I have updated the code. this round i couldn't trap the breakpoint. It just exits the app with `Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException'`

Comment: This error was thrown in which method? Can you debug step by step and find out which line break out?

Comment: the error didn't throw vie exception breakpoint. It just exit the program and the error message i copied was from the `output` tab... I am still trying to figure out where did the exception occur.. 
one additional thing i noticed is that if i use a `togglebutton` to simulate sending of `on` & `off` message alternately, it was fine. it only occurs when it's trigger by the timer.
typically what is the best way to transmit the 485 message in my scenarior?  I saw some `time triggered backgroundtask` example... it is suitable?

Comment: BackgroundTask is suitable. It is also a  non-UI thread which is similar with timer. The   issue is not caused by timer. If possible, please upload the simple project for troubleshooting.

Comment: Hi, I added the link for my sample project.
I am not sure if it's caused by the timer but it seems to occur when the it activates to send `off` message... I am still finding out where it exits the program.

Comment: `System.IO.FileNotFoundException` that i receive does it mean anything? i couldn't get more info.

Comment: @mylim, I have updated my response, please feel free let me know if the issue is fixed.

Comment: @MichealXu-MSFT I was away from the UART for awhile, recent attempts the periodical transmission of UART fails occasionally without throwing any exception. Perhaps i will rewrite the entire code and try again.